# What's the difference between _create() and _multiCreate() in the REST API methods?

Tags: magento-1.8, api, rest-api

I am trying to extend the Magento's REST to have my own set of API.

I looked through the code and figured that there are `_create()`, `_multiCreate()`, `update()`, etc...

What's the difference between these methods in the `V1.php` file?

- `_create()` and `_multiCreate()`
- `_update()` and `_multiUpdate()`
- `_delete()` and `_multiDelete()`

How can I know when I should use which of the 2 functions, the regular or the mutli one?

I couldn't find much documentation on the different methods used to create REST API in Magento.

Comment: Yeah, +1 for lacklustre Magento API docs!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Api2/Product/Website/Rest.php` as an example, we can see `_create` and `_multiCreate` methods.  The main difference between them is that `_multiCreate` is expecting an array of elements to create, much like passing this function a collection.  In this example, we're setting the website that the product is related to, to a single website, or to multiple websites.

Looking at an example of `update` and `multiUpdate` within `code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Api/V2.php` we can see that, again, `multiUpdate` is expecting an array of Product Ids (and Product Data).  In this instance, you can see a subsequent call to the internal `update` function anyway within `multiUpdate`.

`multiDelete` doesn't appear to exist as a concrete implementation within the `core` code.